# Response from AJAX request is only displayed once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've got some code that sends an ajax request when a form is being submitted. This works the first time the form is submitted (it's a search module), but only once. I've added an effect to highlight the table when data is returned, and you can only see it once (the data changes only once as well).

When I look at the response in the chrome dev tools, I can see it contains the data of the new search query but this isn't shown. Why can I only display results once?

JS:

```
$(function () {
// Creates an ajax request upon search form submit
 var ajaxFormSubmit = function () {
    var $form = $(this);

    var options = {
        url: $form.attr("action"),
        type: $form.attr("method"),
        data: $form.serialize()
    };

    $.ajax(options).done(function (data) {
        var $target = $($form.attr("data-nn-target"));
        var $newHtml = $(data);
        $target.replaceWith($newHtml);
        $newHtml.effect("highlight");
    });

    // Prevent default action
    return false;
 };

 $("form[data-nn-ajax='true']").submit(ajaxFormSubmit);
});
```

HTML:

```
<form method="GET" action="@Url.Action("Index", "Show")" data-nn-ajax="true" data-nn-target="#contentlist" class="form-search">
    <div class="input-append mysearch">
        <input type="search" class="span5 search-query" name="query" data-nn-autocomplete="@Url.Action("AutoComplete")" />
        <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Search" />
    </div>
</form>

<div id="contentlist">
    @Html.Partial("_Shows", Model)
</div>
```

Comment: This is not valid: `action="@Url.Action("Index", "Show")"`. Escape your quotes or mix them: `action='@Url.Action("Index", "Show")'` or `action="@Url.Action('Index', 'Show')"`.

Comment: You're destroying your old `contentList` and replacing it with an entirely new node from the new HTML, so are you certain that the new HTML contains the `"contentList"` ID?

Comment: try with
    `$('input[type=submit]').on('click', function(){
     ajaxFormSubmit();
    })`

Comment: @JoeFrambach: Since the form works, I'm guessing that's server-side syntax that gets swapped out. Would be nice to know for certain though.

Comment: @JoeFrambach: I didn't get any errors there, so changing it made no difference. I'm guessing razor could distinguish the intent of each quote. I've changed it to be more generally valid though, thanks.

Comment: @JoeFrambach Razor is smart enough to see what is html-markup and what is C#. In fact I'm pretty sure the single quote ' in C# is used for the Char object so you can't make strings with that.

Comment: You see C#, I see invalid markup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should use `html()` instead of `replaceWith()` method:

```
$target.html($newHtml);
```

Comment: This solved it! It's weird though, since I was following the tutorial video on http://asp.net/mvc and they used `ReplaceWith()` and it worked. Did the functionality change recently perhaps?

Comment: No, it's obviously an error in the tutorial or someone did some test and forget about it

Answer (score 2):

just an idea... try

```
$target.html(data);
```

instead of

```
$target.replaceWith($newHtml);
```

By replaceWith, you might actually remove the div that you want to fill your content in. Then, the second time, it doesnt find the div to insert the content into.